# A question about R shiny ggvis plot tooltips and reactivity

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have an app with a global function that makes a ggvis plot. I use a global function because I recreate the plot many times with slightly different settings. I need the tooltip to respond to some user inputs, but even when reactivity forces a recalculation of the plot, the tooltip does not seem to get recalculated. Here's an example of the issue:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

df = mtcars
df$name = row.names(df)

make_plot <- function(data, slider){
  hover_values <- function(x) {
    gear = data$gear[data$name == x$name]
    paste("gear times slider is:", gear*slider)
    }
  data %>% 
    ggvis(~mpg, ~hp, key := ~name) %>% 
    layer_points() %>% 
    add_tooltip(hover_values, "hover")
  }

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slider", label = "slider:", min = 1, max = 10, value = 1),
  ggvisOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- eventReactive(input$slider, {
    print("remaking plot...")
    make_plot(df, input$slider)
  }) %>% bind_shiny("plot")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can see that the tooltips are calculated using the slider input, but when you run the app, the tooltips do not change when the slider is changed. Can someone explain what is wrong with my approach or what I need to do to get this working?

Comment: The problem seems to be where you are calling `bind_shiny`. Try `output$plot <- eventReactive(input$slider, {make_plot(df, input$slider)%>% bind_shiny("plot")})`

Comment: @MrFlick Look at the documentation for `ggvisOutput()` It needs the `bind_shiny()`. Removing it prevents the plot from rendering at all.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to look at there. When I run the code I suggested, it works. The problem seems to come from you calling the `bind_shiny` outside the `eventReactive`. That help page doesn't seem to be using the `eventReactive`. Are you saying this does not work for you? I still have `bind_shiny` in my suggestion, just in a different place.

Comment: @MrFlick My bad. I didn't look closely enough at your code. Yup, your solution works! Thanks. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MrFlick pointed out that I needed to move where `bind_shiny()` is used. The corrected code for the server function is:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- eventReactive(input$slider, {
    print("remaking plot...")
    make_plot(df, input$slider) %>% 
    bind_shiny("plot")
  })
}
```